# Export current VPC infrastructure

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a lab setup that in aws, with a vpc, an IGW a few different subnets and some ec2 instances, nothing to crazy.

I am trying to export this VPC with everything inside, but can't figure out how to do it.

I tried the cloudformer, but i keep getting errors when trying to create a stack, its keeps saying that i have reached my limit with VPC and IGW.

Is there something better to use that can export this VPC, with all ec2 and everything configured in those ec2 instances.

Answer (score 1):

[Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/), and in particular the TR import tool called [Terraforming](http://terraforming.dtan4.net/) are very good for this type of work.

Though there is a learning curve associated with Terraform, and it's probably a good idea to start gradually with it.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is **no such tool or functionality provided** by AWS.

**CloudFormer** is an old, no longer maintained and non-reliable project (in beta for years) as you already experienced.

You may also hear about **importing existing resources into CloudFormation**. But this is also not useful in your use case, as this works with only some resources and requires **manual** preparation of templates for resources to be imported.

The only choice is to look for **tools outside of AWS**. @AbiDembak alread recommended one such tool.